# Firefox loads specific subpage whenever browsing to homepage

Tags: firefox, redirection

My homepage works fine with Internet Explorer.

But if I load [the homepage](http://appliancerepairrus.com) in Firefox, Firefox opens a specific page, [washer.html](http://appliancerepairrus.com/washer.html).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just pulled up http://appliancerepairrus.com in Chrome 10 and got redirected to http://appliancerepairrus.com/washer.html.

Answer (score 1):

Your website uses [Google website optimizer](http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer) to do a so-called [A/B test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing). This will randomly show *some* visitors (in your case: *some* browser) another page.

Removing

```
<script>utmx("url",'A/B');</script>
```

should help. If you cannot remove that yourself, then I guess there must be some setting in Google web optimizer itself, which defines which pages are shown. Just have both pages refer to the homepage then.

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled it up in FF 4, and it loaded the root page, as expected.  Perhaps your browser has cached a redirect request; try clearing it's cache and hitting the root page again.